# Why do comparison operators exist between C++ containers?

Tags: c++, containers, std, c++17

My problem, or rather, the issue that bothers me, is that the following code compiles:

```
auto nonsense = std::vector<int>{20,30,40,50} < std::vector<int>{21,29,41,49}
```

Why would this be the case ?

What is the meaning of the comparison ?

It seems to me that it is not obvious (aka could be mean comparison, sum of the comparison between all the values, max/min comparison, length comparison, comparison of the whole memory area allocated... etc) what "comparing two arrays" means outside of the `==` and `!=` case, so why would these operators exist ? What is or was their intended purpose ? Why have they been introduced and why are they not removed from the standard ?

Comment: There are probably enough use cases for [lexicographical comparison](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/operator_cmp) that these operations exist.

Comment: The answer is in the language specification. Why are you asking here?

Comment: I think you would get less downvotes if you formulated your question in a slightly less combative fashion. Maybe drop the "... and why are they not removed from the standard ?" part.

Comment: This is opinion-based. The answer (including the current one) can pretty much just say: because someone think it's a good idea, but you don't.

Comment: There is no "inequality" (aka "not equal": `!=`) operator shown in your code.

Comment: I meant to say comparison, not sure why I typed `inequality` my brain farted

Answer (score 3):

Firstly, `std::vector` is a well designed structure and while this "feature" may seem odd at first, it makes sense for it to exist in the standard.

Before we discuss *why* we should first know *what*.

When you use the `<` `<=` `>=` `>` operators comparing two vectors, you are preforming a [lexicographical](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexicographical_order) comparison (more specifically, it's literally `std::lexicographical_compare` which you can read about [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/lexicographical_compare)).

[These overloads](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/operator_cmp) were presented as a short-hand way to compare to vectors. It may not seem useful to you, but it's a great way to compare two vectors. If you have another idea in mind for vector comparison, it's up to you to implement it.

The standard can only do so much, and even if it seems niche or not useful there's always a reason why. In this case, it was because the committee agreed that a lexicographical comparison was the most sensible to be the "default".

Comment: Well, my question is to do more with "why" a default exists, rather than to what the default should do. It seems to be like a shorthand way of writing `std::lexicographical_compare` wouldn't be worth adding such an "abstract" feature to a class where most other methods and operators are "obvious". As in, it's quite nice I can use `emplace_back` rather than doing the capacity check, last() itter position check, possible realloc and move myself, since that's one things anyone wants to do with a vector. But why would `lexicographical_comp` be so widely used ? As opposed to, say, mean comparison ?

Comment: @George: It's important to recognize that the STL-derived classes have a *mathematical* foundation. `vector` is not a dynamically sized array; it is container which represents a mathematical *vector*: an ordered collection of elements of some dimensional. As such, defaulting to a lexicographical comparison makes perfect sense.